# Why two series are cointegrated but not mean-reverting?

Tags: regression, linear-model, cointegration

I'm checking a timeserie with:

- **ADF** (unitroot)
- **KPSS** (unitroot)
- **Phillips-Ouliaris** (cointegration)

the results are:

**Phillips-Ouliaris**

```
Phillips-Ouliaris demeaned = -2175.5676, Truncation lag parameter = 20, p-value = 0.01
```

**ADF:**

```
Dickey-Fuller = -3.7275, Lag order = 12, p-value = 0.02261
```

**KPSS:**

```
KPSS Level = 17.6846, Truncation lag parameter = 10, p-value = 0.01
```

Could someone explain me how is it possible that a serie (aka: the residuals of a linear regression), pass the ADF test, pass the cointegration test, but **fails** kpss?

What do you think?

Comment: A plot of the residuals could be useful to say more about the results. Note that ADF and KPSS critical values are defined for the univariate time series. The critical values for cointergation in ADF case are more negative, depending on the number of explanatory variables included.

Comment: To add to Dmitrij's comment, ADF and KPSS are not suited for testing the unit root in **residuals**. Furthermore they have a bunch of parameters, which you omit (trend, no trend, quadratic trend, etc). I suggest to proceed in orderly fashion for cointegration. First determine what precisely are your series (drift, no drift, trend, no trend) and then use cointegration test such as Johansen.

Comment: @mpiktas Why residuals are not good to testunit root?

Comment: @Black, take the simple case: $u_t=\rho u_{t-1}+v_t$, where $v_t$ is white noise. Unit root test that $rho=1$. Suppose $y_t=\beta x_t+u_t$ and you want to test whether $u_t$ has unit root or not. However residual $\hat{u}_t=u_t-x_t(\hat\beta-\beta)$. So if for example $u_t=u_{t-1}+v_t$, then $\hat{u}_{t}=\hat{u}_{t-1}+v_t-(x_t-x_{t-1})(\hat\beta-\beta)$. So although $u_t$ is a unit-root with iid white noise, $\hat{u}_t$ is not. Since the ADF expects the former, the usual p-values might be incorrect.

Comment: @mpiktas, residuals are like the spread (variance from linear relathionship), spread = y - (BETA * x). Could you explain (in words) why you don't think it? Thanks you! (P.S.1 Take a look at: http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html He is testing the spread (as i mentioned) with AdF)